# How to set up the path in newBufferWriter

Tags: java, java-7, java.nio.file

How can i set up the path right to `newBufferWriter`. I'm getting the example usage of the `newBufferWriter` from oracle page:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
String s = ...;
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, charset)) {
    writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
}
```

I'm comfused how to set the `file` parameter, Where should i get the `Path` object, for example i want to create file in a directory , so i have to set a `Path` object, and in this code the path object is `file` parameter so , how to give it a string value ? or how to give it any value of a directory where i want to create a certain file ?

And something else, what about that exception ? What does it mean ?

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/Path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` for `java.nio.file.Path` then there is something wrong with your Java environment. You are most likely mixing Java versions; compiling with JDK 7, but trying to run on Java 6 or older. What do you get when you type `java -version`?

`Path` in Java 7 is more or less the replacement for `File` in Java 6 and older.

You can get a `Path` like this:

```
Path file = Paths.get("myfile.txt");
```

Comment: Yes, yes thanks, the exception was about that , i fixed it and thanks about the path, but actualy i needed something like not to get, but to set, and this is the answer with path object and createtempfile.Thanks a'lot man :)